# Matlab: sum every 8 cells and divide value over those 8 cells

Tags: arrays, matlab, sum

I have a large array and I want to sum every 8 cells in this array. Then I want to assign the mean value of those 8 cells to each of the cells. Example for 16 cells:

```
0
0
3.69230000000000
4.54440000000000
0
0
1.20710000000000
0
0
0
0.213020000000000
0
0
0
0
0.355030000000000
```

would become:

```
1.1805
1.1805
1.1805
1.1805
1.1805
1.1805
1.1805
1.1805
0.0710
0.0710
0.0710
0.0710
0.0710
0.0710
0.0710
0.0710
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: When you say “cells” I think you have a cell array rather than a numeric array. Please include a bit of MATLAB code that creates an example array with similar properties to your actual array, so that we might be certain about the inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `splitapply` to generate the mean of each group, where the groups are defined by repeating `1:N` 8 times each, with `N=numel(a)/8` being the number of blocks.

Then just use `repelem` to expand this back to the same size as the input `a`.

```
m = splitapply( @mean, a, repelem(1:numel(a)/8,1,8).' );
m = repelem( m, 8, 1 );
```

Substitute whatever aggregation function you want in for `@mean`

You could make this more generic with very little improvement so that it can handle the case where your input is not exactly divisible into blocks of 8. In this case by just using a smaller "leftover" block if needed

```
g = repelem(1:ceil(numel(a)/8),1,8).';
m = splitapply( @mean, a, g(1:numel(a)) );
m = m(g(1:numel(a)));
```

Answer (score 4):

First, reshape the array to an `8x*` array:

```
a = [0 0 3.69230000000000 4.54440000000000 0 0 1.20710000000000 0 0 0 0.213020000000000 0 0 0 0 0.355030000000000]';

a_r = reshape(a, 8, []);
```

Then, calculate the mean of this array over the first axis:

```
m = mean(a_r, 1);
```

Finally, create an `8x1` array of ones, multiply it by `m`, and reshape the result to a single column:

```
result = reshape(ones(8, 1) * m, [], 1)
```

(or, as Cris suggests, use `repmat` to tile the `m` array:

```
result = reshape(repmat(m, 8, 1), [], 1);
```

This gives:

```
   1.180475
   1.180475
   1.180475
   1.180475
   1.180475
   1.180475
   1.180475
   1.180475
   0.071006
   0.071006
   0.071006
   0.071006
   0.071006
   0.071006
   0.071006
   0.071006
```

Comment: You could use `repmat` instead of multiplying by `ones`. Not sure which would be cleaner code.